# How to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a $2\times2$ matrix with complex numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am stuck on a homework problem that asks me to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the following matrix:

$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -1 \\
2 & 3
\end{array}\right]
$$

I know that I have to solve the equation $$Av=\lambda v$$ where v is a nonzero vector and $\lambda$ is a scalar. I also know that this is equivalent to solving $$\det(A-\lambda I)=0$$ where I is the identity matrix. This gives me the characteristic polynomial for A: $$\det(A-\lambda I)=\left|\begin{array}{cc}
1-\lambda & -1 \\
2 & 3-\lambda
\end{array}\right|=(1-\lambda)(3-\lambda)+2=\lambda^2-4\lambda+5$$

However, when I try to find the roots of this polynomial using the quadratic formula, I get complex numbers: $$\lambda_1=2+i$$ and $$\lambda_2=2-i$$

I don't know how to deal with complex numbers in this context. How do I find the eigenvectors that correspond to these eigenvalues? Do I have to use complex arithmetic or is there a simpler way?

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Trust your gut - the process works the same!

Comment: If you learn math, you should get comfortable working with complex numbers at some point.

Comment: A 2-for-1 deal: If the matrix $A$ has real entries and $\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvector of eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $\overline{\mathbf{v}}$ is an eigenvector of eigenvalue $\overline{\lambda}$ as well. (Complex conjugate is applied to the entries of the vector.)

Comment: There is no difference in the process, except that complex numbers need to be manipulated. For $\lambda_1$, we have 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1-2-i & -1 \\ 2 &3-2-i\end{bmatrix} \implies \begin{bmatrix} -1-i & -1 \\ 2 &1-i\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
Now $R_1 \rightarrow R_1/(-1-i)$, you get 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{-1}{-1-i}  \\ 2 &1-i\end{bmatrix}
$$
I think you can take it from here to complete the reduced echelon form. You may find using complex conjugate helpful here.